# Show Google ads on html page

Tags: ads, adsense

I want to show google ads on html page and I doesn't know anything about google ads.

Can Anyone please help me to show ads on html page

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to sign up to https://www.google.com/adsense/. This will give you a HTML snippet you will need to paste onto your HTML page. Google are usually very good with their how-to tutorials.

AdSense Help - Get started with ad code
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181947

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on wordpress, you can also just install the plugins : )